# How to hide Country Field in form checkout and country text in Your Progress checkout magento 1.9

Tags: magento

I used magento 1.9.1.1 and trying to change template in:

> app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping.phtml
>   app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
>   app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml

I try edit

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

and add "no-display" in:

```
<div class="field no-display">
<label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

But Country dropdown still display in form checkout and Your Progress checkout. 
can you help me. thankyou!

Comment: thank @Kamal. CUSTOMERS -> persistent shopping cart -> Persistence Enabe is No. what should i do?

Comment: @Andre has given correct suggestion.. If persistence is not enabled then you should turn on template hints/install MagePsyco template hints extension.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn on template path hints in admin and find the exact template you need to modify without guessing.
You might have a 3rd party extension installed that has changed which template is used here